# CS50 - Credit Card Assignment; Segmentation fault

Tags: c, cs50

Still working on it but when I try to run the program I keep getting the error. I'm very new to programming so can't even see any issues at this point.
This is an assignment for the CS50 course; called credit card.

Also any constructive comments would be highly appreciated :)

Code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int n = 0; //n is length of card number
    int i = 0; //i is the digit 
    int m = 0;
    int p = 0;
    string s = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("Card Number: \n");
        string s = GetString(); //card number

        n = strlen(s);
  
        printf("%s\n", s);
    
        for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
           if (i %2 == 0)
           {
                m = ((s[i] - '1')*2);
                if (m < 10)
                {
                    p = p + m;  //p is product m is numerical value
                }
                else
                {
                    p = 1 + p + (m -10);
                }
           }   
           else
           {
            p = p + (s[i] - '1');
           }
        }
        if (p % 10 ==0)
        {
            if (n == 15 && s[1] == 3 && (s[2] == 4 | s[2] == 7))
            {
                printf("AMEX\n");
            }
            if (n == 16 && s[1] == 5 && (s[2] == 1 | s[2] == 2 | s[2] == 3 | s[2] == 4 | s[2] == 5))
            {
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");
            }
            if ((n == 3 | n==16) && s[1] == 4)
            {
                printf("VISA\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        }
    }
   // while ();
}
```

Comment: Segmentation fault most often indicates access to non-existing memory.  On example is access an array entry with to larger or small of an index.  A common beginner programming error is not validating input.  What would happen if the professor threw you a curve and returned a string of, say two characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the first declaration of string.

Also, I see that the while condition in the do-while loop is commented out. If it is meant to be used for the input though, the for loop which iterates over the string to analyze the number shouldn't be included in it. The do-while loop should terminate after the input is received and the program should then progress to the for loop.